# How does computer store non-repeating decimal very accurately?

Tags: floating-point

Maybe it is not accurate at all, but it looks very accurate for me.
I'm making a scientific calculator for my portfolio, and I found an interesting phenomenon.

Because computers store decimals not accurately but approximately, I thought that ***asin(sin(30rad))*** wouldn't give 30rad, and ***sqr(sqrt(7))*** wouldn't give 7, etc..

However, it seems that every kind of calculations like above gives an accurate result. (I used **cmath** header of c++, and I checked that python **math** modules also gives the same)

This consequence seems even arcane to me. Does the computer really store those non-repeating deicmals? or is it just a matter of implementation of math libraries, like substituting a special symbol for them?

Comment: Read the Wikipedia article on floating point.

Comment: The results you see are just an illusion. They are rounded, hiding from you small rounding errors.

Comment: The last sentence of your question hints at something called "symbolic computation". In your case c++/python are just using floating point and you're "lucky" to get the right answer, but there do exist systems that can evaluate such expression exactly.

Comment: Here is also proof that C++ doesn't compute the exact answer. It only looks like it: [https://ideone.com/ZwNbds](https://ideone.com/ZwNbds)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may be that sqr (sqrt (7)) is *displayed* as 7, but it isn't actually exactly equal to 7. That's something you need to check. What you see is not always what you get. It may be that sqr (sqrt (7)) *is exactly* 7, by "coincidence" (not really coincidence, more like "unpredictable with my limited knowledge").

Take any floating point number x, 1 ≤ x < 4. When the square root is calculated, you get another floating point number y, 1 ≤ y ≤ 2. There are fewer floating point numbers (about half as many) 1 ≤ y ≤ 2 as floating point numbers 1 ≤ x < 4. If you square two numbers y and y', that calculation doesn't know how y and y' were created. So there are about half as many floating point numbers sqr (sqrt (x)), 1 ≤ x ≤ 4, as original numbers in that interval. So for about half the numbers, sqr (sqrt (x)) ≠ x.

The other way round, calculating sqrt (sqr (x)), you can probably prove that the result must be equal to x if both operations are calculated with high quality. If the squaring operation produces a relative error epsilon, then the square root operation divides that relative error by two.

PS. Yuval checked that for x = 7, sqr (sqrt (x)) is *not* equal to x. If you checked all integers from 1 to 10,000 except those that are squares, I'd expect that sqr (sqrt (x)) equals x in about half the cases that you check.

Comment: Indeed, 5105 of the integers from 1 to 10000 satisfy `math.sqrt(n)**2==n`.

Comment: @gnasher729 It probably would make sense to mention the term "pigeonhole principle" in addition to the current textual description.

Comment: @njuffa I wouldn't really like to do that. It feels inappropriate.

Comment: @gnasher729 I am not quibbling with the choice, but I am puzzled in which sense this would be *inappropriate*? Am I overlooking something? Trying to fit the roots of $2^{n}$ floating-point numbers into $2^{n-1}$ available encodings seems like a textbook example of that principle, i.e. we know there must be collisions.

Answer (score 3):

If you compute the square root of 7 and then square it, you won’t get exactly 7. Here is what I get in python:

> >>> math.sqrt(7)**2
>
> 7.000000000000001

And here is what you get if you print the value instead:

> >>> print math.sqrt(7)**2
>
> 7.0

What happened? When printing a floating point value, the default precision is 12 decimal digits (in python). Since `math.sqrt(7)**2` differs from 7 in the 15th digit, when rounding to 12 digits we just get 7, giving you the illusion that there is no error.

Answer (score 0):

Let's play with "bc -l"

- IEEE single : 1 (sign) + 8 (exp) + 23 (mantissa)   [+1 hidden]
- IEEE double : 1 (sign) + 11 (exp) + 52 (mantissa )  [+1 hidden]

sqrt(7) = 
10.10100101010011111111010100111010010111110001110100110110111100011\
10011101010011111100110000111111100001101111010001000001101010101001...
(binary)

With single precision, we store 23bits :

**SQ7S** = 10.1010010101001111111101 [next truncated bits are 010011...]
(no additional rounding needed)

With double precision, we store 52 bits :

**SQ7d** = 10.101001010100111111110101001110100101111100011101001 [next trucated bits are 1011...]

Due to the default "round to nearest-even" rounding rule, this double precision number will be rounded up to :

**SQ7D** = 10.101001010100111111110101001110100101111100011101010

Calculating the square :

**SQ7S** * **SQ7S** = 110.111111111111111111111 [00100...]
 = 6.999999523... (decimal)

**SQ7D** * **SQ7D** = 111.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 [1011...]

rounded to :
**SQ7D** * **SQ7D** = 111.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 
= 7.000000000000000888... (decimal)

**So : Neither single nor double precision IEEE float gives exact result to sqr(sqrt(7)), but the double precision result is closer, of course.**

(I have also tried with x87-style long double, 64bits mantissa, and it is still wrong)